# Update row data in table using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a table with first td of checkbox I want to click on the checkbox and value of all td elements of the selected row can pop up in a form where I can update the data and on submit the data overwrite the previous values of the row td elements. Please note that this is all happening on the same page with one pop-up (bootstrap modal).

Comment: Please explain it briefly ! I guess till you want to get different form datas when checking different checkbox right? If not correct me

Comment: https://codepen.io/ErZeeshan/pen/ZxoREV

Comment: The above codepen link can describe more to you, I want to update the data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate out your issues, once you have the data you can place it where you like.

**Retrieve the table row that was selected**

```
$('table#checkbox-table td:first input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {
  // from input go up parents twice (for <tr/> element)
  var $selectedRow = $(this).parents().eq(1);
  selectedRow($selectedRow);
});

function selectedRow($selectedRow) {
  // do something with $selectedRow...
}
```

Comment: This link can share my problem in depth, I want to update the data. https://codepen.io/ErZeeshan/pen/ZxoREV